# ¿Como aplicar una Promise entre dos funciones?

Tags: javascript, angular, promesas

Tengo un formulario en mi aplicacion Angular con las siguientes dos funciones.

Una primera que se activa con el click de dos botones. Los gestiono con un if y un else.
En el caso de pasar por el else realizo una serie de acciones, la primera de ella lanzo un loader y por ultimo llamo a la suscripcion de un componente.

```
 handleClick() {

    if (this.isDisabledSaveButton) { 
      this.setData();
    } else {
      this.emitLoader = true;
      this.showForm();
      this.hideTools();
      this.component.submit();

    }
  }
```

y la segunda funcion se llama con el this.component.submit() llamo a otra funcion que realiza una suscripcion y tiene muchas condiciones en funcion de las selecciones dentro del formulario y por ultimo paro el loader porque se ha terminado la suscripcion.

```
  setForm() {
    this.loadFooter = false;
    if (this.formSubscription !== undefined) {
      this.formSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

//logica sobre las condiciones que antes comentaba

        this.emitLoader = false;
        this.blockButtons();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if (this.submitAction = false) {
            resolve({success: true, data: this.submitAction});
          } else {
            reject({success: false});
          }
        });
      });

    }, 0);
  }
```

el problema viene cuando al final de la primera funcion quiero hacer una redireccion dentro del else.

```
handleClick() {

    if (this.isDisabledSaveButton) { 
      this.setData();
    } else {
      this.emitLoader = true;
      this.showForm();
      this.hideTools();
      this.component.submit();
      this.setForm().then((result: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      });

    }
  }
```

Necesito esperar a que la suscripcion finalice y se ponga a false el loader para poder realizar la redireccion, si no no habré grabado los datos del form.
Por ello estoy intentando implementar por primera vez una promesa , pero por mas ejemplos que miro no soy capaz de lograrlo.

Entiendo que debo crear la promesa al final de la segunda funcion pero no veo como llamarla en la primera.
En cuanto hago la llamada al .then me devuelve un error
"Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'."

Por mas tutoriales que he visto no entiendo como relacionar ambas funciones a traves de la promesa.
Que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias a todos por adelantado.

Comment: La respuesta esta en tu misma pregunta: **Necesito esperar a que la suscripcion finalice y se ponga a false el loader para poder ...** cuando pase esto resuelves tu promesa **resolve** en caso contrario **reject** tienes que manejarla con **.then** ahi vendrá el **resolve** te dejo un enlace para que investigues mas sobre el manejo de promesas : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVQR8TjjAWA

Answer (score 0):

Agrego un ejemplo de promesa:

```
setForm() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // aquí va todo el código asíncrono que
      // deseas ejecutar, cuando todo haya finalizado
      // se llama el método resolve o reject
      // resolve es cuando se ejecutó correctamente
      // con reject se retorna un error

      setTimeout(() => {
        // luego de una espera de 2 segundos
        // se devolverá este valor
        resolve("valor de retorno");
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  
  esperarSetForm(){
    // resto del código

    this.setForm().then(resultado => console.log(resultado));
  }
```

Comment: Por mas vueltas que le doy en todo cuando hago el .then al final de submit() me devuelve en mismo error "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'." He tratado de hacer una funcion intermedia para llamarla despues en el submit(), pero me da el mismo error

Comment: Si te devuelve ese error es porque la función en la que llamas `then()`  no está retornando una promesa.